# Increment in Android SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to update the col_Item_Auto_ID column with +1 in each column

Like this: replace 10 with 11, 11 with 12, etc!!
Help me pls... here the code is,

```
 public void updateMiddleTemp(int autoid) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int id=51;


        ContentValues cv_temp1 = new ContentValues();
        cv_temp1.put(col_Item_Auto_ID, col_Item_Auto_ID+1);
        //ff

        long stemp = db.updateWithOnConflict(Table_KOT_ITEMS_TEMP, cv_temp1,
                col_Item_Auto_ID + " >= " + autoid, null,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    db.close();
    }
```

Comment: What problems do you encounter? Do you get an error message?

Comment: the value is not getting updated..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code, it works fine:

```
 db.execSQL("UPDATE " + Table_KOT_ITEMS_TEMP + " SET "
                    + col_Sl_No + " = " + col_Sl_No + " +1 WHERE "
                    + col_Sl_No + " >" +into);
db.close();
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot do this with standard `update` method - you need to use `execSql` method instead:

```
String sql = "UPDATE " + Table_KOT_ITEMS_TEMP +
             " SET " + col_Item_Auto_ID + "=" + col_ITEM_AUTO_ID + "+1" +
             " WHERE " + col_ItemAutoID + " >= " + autoid;

db.execSql(sql);
```

Comment: could you please refer me something for that?

Comment: Hmm.... The documentation for execSql says pretty clearly not to use it for Updates - are you sure this is the only way to do it?

Comment: @andygeers I know it does, yet at the same time android does not provide any other methods for updating rows with using values from the rows, therefore, yes, this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `updateWithOnConflict()`.

The value provided for the value field in `ContentValues` is incorrect.
Resulting value should be "**col_Item_Auto_ID + 1**" and not "**col_Item_Auto_ID1**".
 So try changing

```
cv_temp1.put(col_Item_Auto_ID, col_Item_Auto_ID+1);
```

to

```
cv_temp1.put(col_Item_Auto_ID, col_Item_Auto_ID+"+1");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
String query = "UPDATE " + Constants.RecentChats.DB_RECENT_CHATS + " SET "
                         + Constants.RecentChats.UNREAD_COUNT + " = "
                         + Constants.RecentChats.UNREAD_COUNT +"+1"+ " WHERE "
                         + Constants.RecentChats.JID + " =" + id;

db.execSQL(query);
```